# How can I pass only an Id as parameter of another class in DTO?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

i'm creating a CRUD using SpringBoot,  I'm having an problem to create a Adress, PostgreSQL when I pass that data:

```
'{
  "street": "string",
  "users": 1
}'


org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "teste" of relation "address" violates not-null constraint
  Detalhe: Failing row contains (string, null).
```

Basicly my idea is create a Adress with String street and link an User to this "Adress", howhever i'm having problem to create

I want create a new Adress  using a String street and Id as foreign key to table Users. Thats my code:

**ADDRESS**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
@IdClass(Address.class)
public class Address implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teste")
    private User users;


    @Id
    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

  /// Getter and setter
}
```

**USER**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="username")
@Embeddable
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
    private List<Address> adress;
 //Getter and setter
}
```

**AdressDTO:**

```
public class AddressDto {

    @NotBlank
    private String street;

    @NotNull
    private long users;

    public AddressDto() {}

    public AddressDto(String street, User user) {
        this.street = street;
        this.users = user.getId();
    }

    public long getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(long users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, User> {
}
```

Why my query return error about null value?

Comment: Are you sure that these are the only columns in the address entity?

Comment: Yes @AbdullahKhaled

It's a spring boot starter test